# Regular Expression find method

Tags: java, regex

This is my code to find `"ab"` pattern in given string.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class RegExp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ab");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("ababbaba");
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.start());
        }
    }
}
```

But i am not able to understand internal working of `find()` and `start()`.

Comment: To understand internal working, you should read the source. But perhaps you want to explain what you expected to see, and what it is that you don't understand.

Comment: Classic "Read the fine manual" question. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()

Comment: @RealSkeptic Just right. You wrote the same suggestion I added in my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The `find` method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern and returns a `boolean` indicating the success of failure.

Internally `find` method calls the `search` method (access control default) so that initiates a search to find a `Pattern` within the given bounds. At each match the bound will be incremented until all the matches were found.

Behind the `Matcher` class it's a state machine that will hold the state of the match.

On the other hand `start` method returns the start index as `int` of the subsequence captured by the latest match.

If you want really go deeper I suggest to review the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java) of `Matcher`  class.

Answer (score 3):

As you can read [in the documentation of `find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()):

> Attempts to **find the next subsequence** of the input sequence that
>   matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a
>   previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has
>   not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the
>   previous match.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods.

So when you call `matcher(String text)` the first time **nothing happens**. It is only when you call `find()`, that it aims to find the *first* match. If you call `find()` a second time, it will aim to find the next match and so on.

The following *sequence diagram* describes what happens:

[image: sequence diagram of the code]

The matcher is constructed and each time `find()` is called the "cursor" is moved to the next match.